# c - Valgrind - "Invalid write of size 1"

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

I'm completely lost on this, despite now trying to look for a solution for about two hours:

Valgrind is spitting out a bunch of invalid read of size 1 and invalid write of size 1 with this code, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
char *movieGetDirector(const movie *m)
{
 char *tmp = NULL ;
 tmp = malloc(strlen(m->director)+1) ;
 strcpy(tmp, m->director) ;
 return tmp ;
}
```

It's getting an invalid read of size 1 on the line with strlen and then an invalid write on the strcpy line. I know that m->director is definitely a string, since testing it with gdb does reveal that it is a string and it has text. All of the solutions on google for this error relate to not having that +1 there, but I have it there and it's still an issue. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `m` and how is it initialized? What is `m->director` and how is it initialized? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, including how you initialize the structure and its members, and how you call the function.

Comment: Are you sure `m->director` points to a zero terminated string in valid memory?

Comment: Are you sure `m->director` was allocated/stored ok with _its_ null termination before passing it in?

Comment: How can I check that? There is no \0 at the end of the string in GDB, but I'm not sure that it would appear there?

Comment: @VoidWhisperer I think you may have to read some code and check how the string is created in your test case.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It never explicitly adds a \0 to it, it just copies the data from a function argument where it's like newMovie("Blah blah","Director") by mallocing m->director to the strlen of the second argument + 1, then copying it. I'm not sure if that automatically adds the \0?

Comment: Sth has to be wrong with either  `m` or `director` as present code is correct.

Comment: @pikkewyn if this helps at all, in valgrind it's also saying this under the invalid write thing: ==21705==  Address 0x51fce59 is 0 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd

Comment: So while creating newMovie you are already allocating memory? Why do that second time in geter?

Comment: So you know you have memory for 9 characters, try to continue research with that knowledge by adding some debug prints to your code or try to provide more complete example, link or sth

Comment: Again, *please* give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! Without seeing more code, and also the actual Valgrind output, it's really impossible for us to do anything but guess, and mostly guess *badly*.

Answer (score 2):

your malloc/strlen/strcpy calls look fine.  most likely the code that is setting up `m` and m's `director` field are doing it wrong and the memory is corrupted.  you should double check where that variable is allocated & initialized.

that said, your function seems to be duplicating the existing [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) function.  so you probably want to write:

```
char *movieGetDirector(const movie *m)
{
    return strdup(m->director);
}
```